# SLES - Gnome - Change desktop background using a script

Tags: bash, background-color, gnome, sles

I want to change the desktop background using a script on SLES using GNOME. I just want to set a specific color as the background, no need to use any image or something. I tried using "gsettings" but the command is not available in my SLES (quite old version). The app Gnome uses is the "gnome-background-properties"

Is there any way to manually set a solid color to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really specify which SLES version you're using. 
Try with `gconftool-2` in a terminal instead of `gsettings`.

Like this:
`gconftool-2 -t str --set /desktop/gnome/background/primary_color #fff8e7`